# Upload de imagens no asp net core 1.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Opa galera estou com uma duvida sou novo no .net, aprendi em um curso em asp net mvc 5 so que precisaria pegar aquele codigo de upload e transformar para asp net core se puderem ajudar fico agradecido.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ClienteId,Nome,Email,Endereco,Imagem,ImagemTipo")] Cliente cliente, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var arqImagem = new Cliente
                {
                    ImagemTipo = upload.ContentType
                };
                var reader = new BinaryReader(upload.InputStream);
                arqImagem.Imagem = reader.ReadBytes(upload.ContentLength);
                cliente.Imagem = arqImagem.Imagem;
                cliente.ImagemTipo = arqImagem.ImagemTipo;
            }
            db.Clientes.Add(cliente);
            db.SaveChanges();
            TempData["mensagem"] = string.Format("{0}  : foi incluído com sucesso", cliente.Nome);
            return RedirectToAction("Catalogo");
        }

        return View(cliente);
    }
```

O model

```
[Table("Clientes")]
public class Cliente
{

    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o nome do cliente")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o email do cliente")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o endereço do cliente")]
    public string Endereco { get; set; }
    public byte[] Imagem { get; set; }
    public string ImagemTipo { get; set; }
}
```

E a chamada para a View

```
 public ActionResult ExibirImagem(int id)
    {
        using (ClienteContexto db = new ClienteContexto())
        {
            var arquivoRetorno = db.Clientes.Find(id);
            return File(arquivoRetorno.Imagem, arquivoRetorno.ImagemTipo);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Olá Junior. Evite colocar imagem do código pq dificulta para quem for responder pq tem que digitar todo código da imagem, ao invés disso, use a opção **Amostra de código** para inserir códigos na pergunta. Veja [como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Opa fiz as devidas correções obrigado pelo toque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, tente o seguinte:

```
    // Na sua controller adicione o using
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    // E altere sua action para


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Cliente cliente, IFormFile upload)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (upload != null && upload.Length > 0)
            {
                var arqImagem = new Cliente
                {
                    ImagemTipo = upload.ContentType
                };

                var reader = new BinaryReader(upload.OpenReadStream());
                arqImagem.Imagem = reader.ReadBytes((int)upload.Length);
                cliente.Imagem = arqImagem.Imagem;
                cliente.ImagemTipo = arqImagem.ImagemTipo;
            }
            //db.Clientes.Add(cliente);
            //db.SaveChanges();
            TempData["mensagem"] = string.Format("{0}  : foi incluído com sucesso", cliente.Nome);
            return RedirectToAction("Catalogo");
        }

        return View(cliente);
    }
```

Na sua view adicione:

```
<input type="file" name="upload" />
```

Para caso queira múltiplos  arquivos você irá fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
// Na sua action transformamos o parâmetro em uma lista
public ActionResult Create(Cliente cliente, List<IFormFile> upload)
{
   // qualquer lógica aqui
}
```

Na sua view no input adicione o atributo multiple:

```
 <input type="file" name="upload" multiple />
```

Para informações mais detalhadas confira a [Documentação da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads) sobre o tema

Espero que isso possa ajuda-lo.

Comment: 0
votar contra
accept
 

Opa, obrigado pela resposta como comecei a pouco tempo no asp fiquei em duvida nessa parte, não funcionava no asp core o codigo do asp mvc 5.